# Problems with Access 2002/XP Query after installing office 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've inherited a very large (hundreds of tables & forms) application written in AccessXP. The application runs fine on Windows 7 after install. However, once you install Office 2010, the application experiences a few bugs. The most painful of which is that certain queries take eons longer. What used to take 5 seconds can take upwards of 10-12 minutes. 
The three tables/queries have the following: 
lcltblJC_Final: 40 records. Proper indexes
lkpqryJob: 1964 records. proper indexes on the tables it references
lkpqry_CalculatedCustRespAmount: 2365 records. Proper indexes on the single table it references.

The primary query is this:

```
SELECT lcltblJC_Final.*, 
    lkpqryJob.ScvWr, 
    lkpqryJob.WF_RONum, 
    lkpqryJob.WF_CustRespNote, 
    lkpqryJob.WF_DiscountNote, 
    lkpqryJob.WF_CustRespAmt, 
    lkpqry_CalculatedCustRespAmount.CalcTotal
FROM lcltblJC_Final 
    LEFT JOIN lkpqryJob ON 
        lcltblJC_Final.WF_Shop_ID = lkpqryJob.WF_Shop_Key) 
    INNER JOIN lkpqry_CalculatedCustRespAmount ON 
        lcltblJC_Final.WF_Shop_ID = lkpqry_CalculatedCustRespAmount.WF_Shop_ID
WHERE 
    (lcltblJC_Final.[IncomeCost]+lcltblJC_Final.[COGSCost])<>0;
```

I've removed each of the joins to test where the delay is coming from. lkpqryJob has no problems. lkpqry_CalculatedCustRespAmount is our culprit. That join is the delay we experience. Here is that query:

```
SELECT tblWF_Total.WF_Shop_ID, -[tblWF_Total_CT] AS CalcTotal
FROM tblWF_Total
WHERE (((tblWF_Total.TotalLabel_ID)=1));
```

As you can see, not exactly a scary query here. Any idea why this would get so slow?

Comment: Is the problem that it runs slowly in A2010 or that once O2010 is installed, it runs slowly in Access XP? I'm assuming A2010, so was wondering if you've compacted the database in A2010 to recalculate all the table statistics and all the query optimization.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Been away. The problem is that it runs slowly in Access XP. We haven't converted it to the A2010 runtime yet, as there's a lot of custom menu & custom control work that would have to be redone.

Comment: Have you made sure Access XP is fully re-registered after installing A2010?

Comment: how does one fully re-register that? If you mean we've reinstalled the Access XP runtime afterwords to see if that would fix it, then yes, we've done that. I've wondered if some DLL's get funky after this process, but I wouldn't know which to reregister...

Comment: I didn't realize your Access 2002 (there was only Office XP -- the individual apps in it were only referred to with the year) was the runtime. I don't think there's any way short of commercially available scripts (I forget the name) to allow coexistence of different runtime versions on the same PC.

Comment: The scripts are from SageKey. I've never used them, so I make no recommendations. I do know that they are created by reverse engineering, so are subject to breakage by new versions of Access and updates to your existing Access installations. But they do solve many of the co-existence problems.

Comment: Great, we actually use sagekey for our security. I just found a new release of the runtime from them that says is "2010 compatible", so I'll drop that in and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure last SQL is correct: **-[tblWF_Total_CT] AS CalcTotal**. Column name is missing. I am not saying this will cause the delay but it is certainly missing either column name or "." instead of "_"

Comment: The column name is actually tblWF_Total_CT, so thats correct. The query works, it just takes forever. Not in love with this schema, but there's too many other things to worry about than naming conventions.

Comment: I would create new table with same columns as tblWF_Total, insert data into new table, delete "buggy" table, rename new table. You can use SELECT INTO for that as well. On the side note, what are the data types used in tblWF_Total table? I would look for Memo, OLE etc...

Answer (score 0):

Does the below query work properly without eating much time. try once

```
SELECT lcltblJC_Final.*,
lkpqryJob.ScvWr,
lkpqryJob.WF_RONum,
lkpqryJob.WF_CustRespNote,   
lkpqryJob.WF_DiscountNote,
lkpqryJob.WF_CustRespAmt, 
((lcltblJC_Final.[IncomeCost])+(lcltblJC_Final.[COGSCost])) as costcalculation,
lkpqry_CalculatedCustRespAmount.CalcTotal FROM lcltblJC_Final
LEFT JOIN lkpqryJob 
ON lcltblJC_Final.WF_Shop_ID = lkpqryJob.WF_Shop_Key
LEFT JOIN 
lkpqry_CalculatedCustRespAmount ON lcltblJC_Final.WF_Shop_ID = 
lkpqry_CalculatedCustRespAmount.WF_Shop_ID 
WHERE costcalculation > 0;
```

Comment: @scott, is it possible to post some sample data for the table 'lcltblJC_Final','lkpqryJob','lkpqry_CalculatedCustRespAmount'? Also, can you change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and see how it works? see my edit.

Comment: @scott, if possible please post some sample data. I can try it and see what's wrong.